# How to run a function with an event listener while running another one with an event listener with canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, dom-events

So I am trying to make a canvas function where it will show in realtime the mouse cursor location within the canvas and when the mouse is clicked it should draw a circle. I found this function that shows the x and y coordinates of the mouse:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", getPosition, false);
}

function getPosition(event) {
  var x = new Number();
  var y = new Number();

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

  if (event.x != undefined && event.y != undefined) {
    x = event.x;
    y = event.y;
  } else // Firefox method to get the position
  {
    x = event.clientX 
      + document.body.scrollLeft 
      + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    y = event.clientY 
      + document.body.scrollTop 
      + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }

  x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
  y -= canvas.offsetTop;
  document.getElementById("position")
    .innerHTML = "X = " 
               + x.toString() 
               + " , Y = " 
               + y.toString();

  canvas.addEventListener("click", drawCoordinates(x, y));
}
```

but I tried to add this function `drawCoordinates()` at the end of the `getPosition()` function which will draw a circle with the 'click' event of the mouse that receives the x and y coordinates:

```
function drawCoordinates(x, y) {
  var pointSize = 3; // Change according to the size of the point.
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");


  ctx.fillStyle = "#ff2626"; // Red color

  ctx.beginPath(); //Start path
  ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Draw a point using the arc function of the canvas with a point structure.
  ctx.fill(); // Close the path and fill.
}
```

but it won't work. The cursor keeps drawing and won't wait for the click event

I tried. using the `addEventListener` but it didn't do what I was expecting it to do

Comment: Why do you initialize `x` and `y` let alone with `new Number`? At any rate, `drawCoordinates(x, y)` isn’t a function; `addEventListener` needs a _function_ as the second argument, but `drawCoordinates(x, y) === undefined`. And using `canvas.addEventListener` inside `getPosition` definitely isn’t what you want; you’re binding an entirely new event listener every single mouse move. Even if you bound it correctly, a single click would fire hundreds of event listeners at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a pointer object and then use events as they occur on the canvas. The function selected prior to the event can be set on the pointer object, so that the same actions--provided a previous action set the function for the event--can be used to call different functions.  I only have relatively complex examples for scripts that read handwriting, automatically create math in canvas or draw shapes on voice command or user input. If you give a more specific simple example, I can give you a specific answer.